# RSA Public-Key Cryptosystem, Discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to learn how data encryption works but i am clueless with the book examples.
If possible can anyone teach me how they would encrypt a sentence like:-

```
I like soccer
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. Take ASCII codes for the letters:
   $x_0, \ldots, x_{12} = 73, 32, 108, 105, 107, 101, 32, 115, 111, 99, 99, 101, 114$.  Each of these is from $0$ to $2^{8}-1$.
2. Put them together into a single number, e.g. $M = \sum_{i=0}^{12} 2^{8i} x_i = 9063388665844398324195766575177$.
3. Let's say your public key is $n = 2824759655928487097318266149778058357227188396019564850741711$, which happens to be the product of the primes $p =2051948051948051948051948052013$ and $q =1376623376623376623376623376747$, and your encryption exponent is $e = 65537$.
   The private key is $d = 1917726343458293428459978573964670385576664551820649823389401$, which satisfies $e d \equiv 1 \mod \varphi(n)$.  Note also that $M < n$ and $M$ is not divisible by $p$ or $q$ (if it was divisible by one of them, you'd have to modify the message).
4. The encrypted message is $c = M^e \mod n = 2330630545591110796389920181462313972112015020908397976509679$.
5. To decrypt this, using the private key, you compute
   $ M = c^d \mod n = 9063388665844398324195766575177$, then extract the bytes $x_i$ and convert back to characters.